# Understanding an example of an Integral Domain where the Ascending Chain Condition on Principal Ideals is not satisfied

Tags: ring-theory

In Nicholson's Introduction to Abstract Algebra the text gives an example of an Integral Domain in which the ACCP fails. He writes:

> For example, consider $R=\{n+xf\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}, f \in \mathbb{Q[x]} \}$, the set of all polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose constant term is in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $R$ is an integral domain (subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$), but $\langle x\rangle \subset \langle \frac {1} {2} x\rangle \subset \langle \frac {1}{4}x\rangle \dotsb$

I'm not sure what the notation means here. Is $\langle x\rangle = \{ xf\mid x \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \}$
(so the constant term would be $0$)?

I am not sure how to show that there is an ascending chain, insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\in R$, then $\langle g\rangle=\{gf\mid f\in R\}$ is the principal ideal generated by $g$ in $R$.

Clearly $\langle\frac{1}{2^n}x\rangle\subseteq \langle\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x\rangle$, because
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}x=2\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x
$$
and $2\in R$. On the other hand, there is no element $h\in R$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x=\frac{1}{2^n}xh
$$
because we can cancel $x$ and evaluating at $0$ would yield $h(0)=1/2$. Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x\notin\Bigl\langle\frac{1}{2^n}x\Bigr\rangle
$$
and the inclusion $\langle\frac{1}{2^n}x\rangle\subset \langle\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x\rangle$ is proper.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much for the help I understand now.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Sorry, typo.

Comment: I edited my question as the last part didn't make sense I realized.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yes, you were reversing the inclusion. I believe that both the question and the answer are clearer now.